# NetworkX get node with only one neighbours

Tags: python, networkx

I got a list of connected components from NetworkX. I would like to get the node from the connected components that only has 1 neighbour without looping each of the node in the connnected components manually. My question is: is there a way to do it or a built-in function from networkx that can do that?

```
 for cc in nx.connected_components(networkx_graph):
      for node in cc:
           
           if len(list(networkx_graph.neighbors(node))) == 1:
                 lst.append(node)          
                 break
``
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the networkx `Graph` object does not maintain a mapping of node degree to node identities, so you will have to query all nodes to find nodes with degree 1. However, your query can be expressed more succinctly:

```
for cc in nx.connected_components(networkx_graph):
    lst = [node for node, degree in networkx_graph.degree(cc) if degree == 1]
```